# memory map with multiple handles - Can we use multiple handles to memory map a file

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management, operating-system

In a process is good decision to use multiple memory maps with **different** handles?

Currently we are using single file handle with multiple memory maps since it is single handle we are using synchronization lock across the threads while reading file.

With the new approach of different handles we will avoid the lock and trying to get the performance benefit out of this

However would like to know how the Virtual memory manager behaves when i use different handles. will this acts concurrently ? 
                              (or)
Though am using different handles since the file is same it behaves sequential and no performance benefit?

Comment: I cannot imagine that your need to guard access to a memory map will in any way be affected by the number of handles to it that exist.

Comment: You mean that should i guard the map even if use different handles ?

Comment: What specifically makes you think you need to synchronize access at all?

Comment: we are using synchronization with different memory maps using single handles. The reason to synchronize is we cannot use the same handles to move between different offsets in the same file . Our maps are using mapped with different offsets of the same file. Hence we cannot use the head(handle) to move between different potions of the file concurrently and that thrashes the windows internal file buffer.

Comment: In general would want to know how the memory manager seeks the data when different memory maps created by using different handles. and the memory maps are created with different offsets of the same file. Will VMM reads the data concurrently ?

Comment: Have you observed an actual problem, or are you just assuming there is one?  What are the symptoms?  As far as I know, accessing a view on a file mapping object does not make use of the file pointer, so there shouldn't be an issue.  (You *are* using a file mapping object, I assume, i.e., the CreateFileMapping function?)